# My path keeps getting truncated and I have to restart explorer.exe to fix it

Tags: windows-7, path, environment-variables

I have a mysterious problem on my machine. Periodically I find that my path on Windows 7 machine gets set to

> %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Chocolatey\bin;C:\GnuWin\bin;C:\sysinternals;C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\

I have to restart explorer.exe and reopen my console windows to fix this. My system path from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` is

> C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files\NirSoft;c:\Program Files (x86)\bind9;C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\9.0\DLLShared;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\KDiff3;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\wsf_c\lib\;c:\Program Files (x86)\p-nand-q.com\GTools;c:\springsource\maven-2.2.1.RELEASE\bin;c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\axis2-1.5.4\bin;c:\Program Files\TortoiseHg;C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet;C:\NuGet\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\Redist\;C:\Program Files\Dependency Walker;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;c:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\ILSpy2;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Mercurial\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nant-0.92\bin;C:\Program Files\10Gen\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.2.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin

My user level path from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` is

> C:\Chocolatey\bin;C:\GnuWin\bin;C:\sysinternals;C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT\

It seems that something is replacing my environments path with `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;` plus the contents of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` without the contents of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

Any ideas what could be the cause of this or how I could log it?