# Is there a way to see current environment variables for a process with WMI?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, monitoring, wmi

I have a weird problem where something is [changing my path in my login session](https://superuser.com/questions/479049/my-path-keeps-getting-truncated-and-i-have-to-restart-explorer-exe-to-fix-it). The permanent path in the registry is not changing.

I wanted to monitor changes to the explorer.exe process's environment variables using [Register-CimIndicationEvent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590757.aspx) with the [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx) CIM object. However, I don't see anything about environment variables there. Is there a property I am missing? Is there another way to get the current environment for another process, and track changes to it?

There is a [Win32_Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394143(v=vs.85).aspx) class. However, it reads from the registry tags where environment variables are stored. It doesn't read the working variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I the environment is not something that is available easily through any API or through WMI.

The simplest route to track your environment would be to make regular checks through [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see when the change is happening.

If you can handle writing a bit of C++ code here are a couple of resource on how to access another process' environment.  You could use that to create a tool to monitor the environment for you:

- [Check for environment variable in another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1202653/94928)
- [Read Environment Strings of Remote Process](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25647/Read-Environment-Strings-of-Remote-Process)

Comment: Hrm, well I'd prefer to just use PInvoke rather than C++, for the same effect. I shall give it a try.

Comment: @JustinDearing: +1 for C#.

Comment: Systernals ProcessExplorer works great for spying on the current environment variables.